# PooledConnectionFactory in endless reconnect loop

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

piece of code below

```
factory = new PooledConnectionFactory(brokerURL);
connection = factory.createConnection("", "");
connection.start();
```

Broker URL is a valid host, but the port is not opened.
After starting it goes into an infinite reconnection loop

```
[junit] 00:28:54,851  WARN FailoverTransport:1109 - Failed to 
connect to [SOME_URL] after: 10 attempt(s) continuing to retry.
[junit] 00:43:01,629  WARN FailoverTransport:1109 - Failed to 
connect to [SOME_URL] after: 20 attempt(s) continuing to retry.
[junit] 00:58:02,531  WARN FailoverTransport:1109 - Failed to 
connect to [SOME_URL] after: 30 attempt(s) continuing to retry.
[junit] 01:13:08,646  WARN FailoverTransport:1109 - Failed to 
connect to [SOME_URL] after: 40 attempt(s) continuing to retry.
[junit] 01:28:10,021  WARN FailoverTransport:1109 - Failed to 
connect to [SOME_URL] after: 50 attempt(s) continuing to retry.
```

How can I set the number of reconnections or reduce the retry interval?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using a failover URL without maxReconnectAttempts (defaults to retry forever).

Below is an example maxReconnectAttempts on a failover URL

```
failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?maxReconnectAttempts=10
```